# How can I delete node_modules? It will not let me under any circumstance due to snoretoast-x64.exe

Tags: npm, node-modules, delete-file

I have tried deleting two Vue/Laravel projects with no success. Each time, everything but node_modules is removed. The only remaining file is snoretoast-x64.exe. I have tried all the following:

**FileAssassin**: Just states I do not have permission to delete the file.

**'Del' key**: States I need admin permissions. When given, says I need permission from myself.

**'Shift'+'Del' keys**: Deletes the .exe, which then immediately regenerates.

**CMD, PowerShell, Git Bash, PuTTy, RimRaf(npm & npx) (All in Administrator Mode)**: State I do not have permission to delete the file.

**Altering security settings under file properties**: States I do not have permission to view permissions.

I've tried looking anywhere I could. This is everything I can remember trying. I'm at a complete loss.

Comment: The people responsible for this, meaning not being able to delete a folder in MY computer without creating any lower permission users, and with checking the "full access" for all the random accounts listed in the security tab of the folder settings by windows, should be put in prison and never be allowed to see the light of day again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After restarting my computer three times, this last one being after the 'Shift'+'Del' key tactic, the files simply ceased to exist. I guess the answer is to 'Shift'+'Del' the files and restart your machine. Weird, but it worked for me.

Comment: I will mark this as the answer once the 2 day wait is up. Thank you for taking the time to look at this!

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue. Could not delete under any circumstance, even force delete from bash didn't work.

Shift delete, would result in the file reappearing if the window was reloaded. But Shift delete , and immediately restart, and then I was able to remove the node_modules folder , and re-run npm install

Thanks!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).